# How to create more SKScene in addition to GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I tried to create a new subclass of SKScene "MainScene" like the one apple created the GameScene.

I want to create more scene in addition to my "GameScene" but its not working.

Below is my subclass code.

**MainScene :**

```
import SpriteKit
#if !os(iOS)
import AppKit
#endif

class MainScene : SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

       }

}
```

**MainSceneViewController :**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = MainScene(fileNamed:"MainScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            //skView.showsFPS = true
            //skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

[image]
**Error :** "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1097f2b20) to 'SKView' (0x108a4cad0)."

Comment: Perhaps it is where you have named your class 'MainView' instead of 'MainScene' where you have declared it, in your UIViewController?

Comment: A lot of people always seem to miss this part, so I am going to ask, did you make a MainScene.sks file

Comment: Then that is your problem `MainScene(fileNamed:"MainScene")` is looking for MainScene.sks, not MainScene.swift.  MainScene.sks is your actual scene file,  it holds all of the preliminary data for a scene.  MainScene.swift is just the code behind the scene to tell it how it should act

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a new scene,  you need to actually create a new scene file,  not just the code behind file.

To create new scene files, go to file, New, File,  then in your sections go to iOS, SpriteKit Scene.  This will create the sks file you need.

edit:

In the case you are getting the error `Could not cast value of type 'UIView'  to 'SKView'`,  this is due to the fact that in your story board,  your ViewControllers main view does not have a custom class of SKView.  In your storyboard file, open up your view controller,  click the view for this controller,  make sure the right panel is visible, and select the identity inspector tab (It is probably the 3rd from left,  looks like a flag or an envelope with a window).  Under Custom Class, look for the class text box, and put in SKView

Comment: output console : Unknown class _TtC6SKView18MainViewController in Interface Builder file. no errors

Comment: are you doing the View?  not the ViewController

Comment: ViewController not view

Comment: you need to do it on the View,  that is what SKView is,  a child class of UIView

Comment: i need to change UIViewController to UIView?

Comment: im not understand you. what i need to do?

Comment: I really do not know how to explain any better,  It should look like this:  http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/009_InterfaceBuilder.png  In the area marked 2,  make sure the view is selected (Like in the pic)  then change the custom class in the area marked 7 by selecting the 3rd icon from the left

Comment: change it to MainViewController?

Comment: no, do not touch MainViewController at all,  whatever you did to MainViewController, undo

Answer (score 4):

To create more `SKScene` in addition to `GameScene`

- Go to `New File`
- Select `Coca Touch Class`
- Click on `Next`
- SubClass : Type Manually `SkScene`
- create
- import `SpriteKit`

Comment: import SpriteKit in the file which you have created