# Changing the initial scene in spritekit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876376/changing-the-initial-scene-in-spritekit), I'm trying to change the initial scene of my game to `FirstScene.swift`.

I changed the following in `GameViewController.swift`:

from:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

to:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "FirstScreen")
```

FirstScreen.swift starts with

```
import SpriteKit
class FirstScreen: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

Also tried :

```
if let scene = FirstScreen(fileNamed: "FirstScreen")
```

I've also tried a new project and still no luck! Any ideas please?

Comment: You should do this logic in the AppDelegate, not after you load your first scene

Comment: Thanks @MSU_Bulldog. Could you kindly guide me on this please? I don't know how exactly to do it in AppDelegate as I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: no, do not do it in the appdelegate, you are doing it in the correct place.  Did you make a FristScreen.sks file?

Comment: No I haven't. Could you kindly post an answer on how to create an sks file for FirstScene please? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create more SKScene in addition to GameScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327794/how-to-create-more-skscene-in-addition-to-gamescene)

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
let scene = FirstScene()
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

view.presentScene(scene)
```

Note that the `SKScene(fileNamed: String)` constructor is used to unarchive a scene from a `.sks` file.

I am assuming you do not have a `FirstScene.sks` file in your project.

Comment: Hi,
Where do I add this ?